# Should We Use The Same Alt Tags For Multiple Images Of The Same Product?

Tags: seo, google-search, images, tags

I have an e-commerce website with thousands of product images. These images don't have alt tags and are showing as missing alt text errors, **so should we use the same alt tags for multiple images of the same product?** Can you give the best solutions according to you?

Thanks!